# Saving a Word document as Web Page, Filtered drastically reduces image resolution

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

I have a document with hundreds of images. When I save the first image (right click and save picture) it ends up with a good resolution as shown below:

[image]

However, when I save the document as `Web Page, Filtered`, all the images end up really low-res. Here's the exact same image afterwards:

[image]

I've tried the following options in the `Save As` dialog with no luck:

- In `Tools > Web Options... > Pictures > Target Monitor` I've set the Pixels Per Inch to the highest value, 120.
- In `Tools > Compress Pictures > Target Output` I've set it to Print (220 ppi).

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you really want to do is display the document on a kindle, you can print/save the word document as a PDF, and then use [MobiPocketCreator](http://www.mobipocket.com/en/DownloadSoft/default.asp?Language=EN) to turn it into a file that the kindle can read.

Kindle 2 and up support PDF natively.

Comment: I'll give it a shot, but do you know what it does to the Arabic?

Comment: Nice suggestion! I should have tried emailing this to a Kindle (as a PDF) earlier but for the most part it looks great without much changes.

Comment: So it doesn't look like Mobipocket Creator is working... I give the PDF file (same one I sent to Kindle) but it's not generating the .mobi file from the PDF. Do you know of any other options?

Comment: Does [this](http://www.fluentin3months.com/convert-pdfs/) link help?

Comment: Also, it seems to me that the PDF rendering technology and the ebook rendering software are mutually exclusive. PDFs are not meant to dynamically reflow so it probably won't help me that Arabic shows up in the PDF. I'll keep you posted on what I find though.

Comment: I've been looking into the same link :) It doesn't help because I can already get to the HTML step very easily, my issue is only with the Arabic image resolution. One thing I'm exploring is exporting the Arabic as PDF files and finding a way to convert those to images.

Comment: In adobe acrobat, you can just convert a pdf to a series of images ([these sites](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/6-ways-to-convert-a-pdf-file-to-a-jpg-image/) can do it as well)

Answer (score 1):

> Any ideas would be appreciated.

You wrote "*any* ideas" so I'm assuming you mean any.

If you can transcribe it into text, that will work best. It does require that the person reading the resulting web page has a suitable font containing those characters, however most people have Arial Unicode which covers a large number of scripts.

If you can use OCR, that might help with the transcription task.

---

Update:

Kindle's proprietary AZW format supports Arabic script - so you may be able to convert Word documents containing Arabic text into Kindle documents by using Amazon's online conversion tools (for which you pay a small fee) - the resulting AZW document being delivered by email to the Kindle device.

Comment: That's a good point, it won't work for this case though since I need the Arabic to be in an image so it can be displayed on a Kindle.

Comment: Just for further clarification, it actually is already text in Word, and I'm using a macro to copy and then paste-special it into an image.